# Удаление знаков переноса строки в bash

Tags: bash

Регулярка извлекает с файла кусок многострочного текста. Следующая задача - получить из него одну  строку. Попробовал sed "s/\r\n//" . Комбинации опробованы различные. Гуглю различные вариации обозначения знака переноса, не получается. За направление правильного гуления скажу большое спасибо ). текст - utf-8.

Comment: Непонятно. Приведите пример текста и желаемый результат.  
А вообще в никсах перевод строки это \n

Comment: stroka3
stroka2
stroka1

stroka1 stroka2 stroka3 - результат
\n разнообразно опробован и без результата. различные флаги sed и tr

Comment: Что-то вы делаете не так :)

    $ cat in.txt
    stroka3
    
    stroka2
    
    stroka1
    
    stroka1 stroka2 stroka3
    
    $ cat in.txt | tr -s '\r\n' ' '
    stroka3 stroka2 stroka1 stroka1 stroka2 stroka3

    $ cat in.txt | tr -d '\r\n' 
    stroka3stroka2stroka1stroka1stroka2stroka3

Comment: нумерация, конечно, спутана

Comment: Добавил в коммент выше вывод tr -d. Всё прекрасно удаляется.

Comment: Спасибо. Вывод терминала похож на нужный ) Но при записи результата в файл ( добавляюю >> out.txt )получаем аналогичный исходному файл.

Comment: Ну это уже вообще мистика - какая разница куда идёт вывод, на консоль или в файл?

Comment: tr -d '\r\n' помог. Спасибо. А ведь попробовал все возможные варианты как будто. Извиняюсь за невнимательность. Но также без результатен.

Comment: `echo -n ..` убирает перенос строк, или [вариант](https://barbitoff.blogspot.com/2020/01/bash-echo.html) ч/з `echo -e "somestring\c" `, правильное направление - посмотреть _man echo, printf, etc.._

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Не глядя :)

```
cat in.txt | tr -s '\r\n' ' ' > out.txt
```

Или, если склеить строки (в примере выше \r\n меняется на пробел):

```
cat in.txt | tr -d '\r\n' > out.txt
```

P.S. '\r\n'  меняем на '\n' для unix-переводов строк.

Answer (score 3):

смотрим содержимое файла in.txt
    ~ $ cat in.txt
    stroka3

```
stroka2

stroka1

stroka1 stroka2 stroka3
```

загоняем всё что в файле в переменную

```
~ $ string=`cat in.txt`
```

с помощью echo выводим содержимое переменной

```
~ $ echo "$string" # переменная в кавычках выдаст с переносами строк
stroka3

stroka2

stroka1

stroka1 stroka2 stroka3
~ $ echo $string # переменная БЕЗ кавычкех выдаст БЕЗ переносов строк
stroka3 stroka2 stroka1 stroka1 stroka2 stroka3
```

Comment: Всё так, но только в случае юниксовых переводов строк. ^M в строке останутся во всех вариантах.

Comment: я так давно на линуксе что и забыл про ^M :)))

Answer (score 1):

^M удаляется так:

```
cat in.txt | tr -d '\r' > out.txt
```